# How do I catch an error from a stored proc within a stored proc in VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, error-handling

I have a stored procedure that calls several others, one of which is failing to insert a row into a table due to a duplicate primary key

The error raised is 
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure ..., Line 16
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '...'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '...'.

I am calling the this from an Excel spreadsheet via VBA, with usual On Error handling in place, but the routine is failing silently without triggering the error.

I'm not sure if this is down to the stored-proc within stored-proc or the severity of the error being too low.

Has anyone experienced anything like this and can suggest a work around?

My initial attempt was to put a BEGIN TRY / BEGIN CATCH block around the stored procedure call, with the CATCH running RAISERROR at a higher severity, but it doesn't seem to be triggering.

Thanks

Comment: I would review your vba code. Get the exact sql code that is being sent and check you receive the error through ssms. Add a breakpoint to the code and step through executing it.

Comment: What does the top-level stored procedure do with the error which comes from the called stored procedure?  Does it exit with an error message?  Showing some actual code (VBA/stored procedure) might help here.

Comment: @TimWilliams Originally it didn't do anything in particular- I assumed it would bubble up.  I tried a catch around the called stored procedure, but it doesn't trigger even though when running from SSMS, I can see the error plainly in the output window.

Comment: @RussellHart - I've done that :) SSMS shows an error that terminates the stored-proc within a stored proc.  The main proc just carries on (I guess the error isn't severe enough).  The VBA code runs through fine, showing no errors at all.  I initially had it just doing a DBCmd.Execute, but changed it to SET rs = DBCmd.Execute in case returning a recordset was required for it to be watching for an error.  Still no luck though :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the outer proc add an explicit transaction. `BEGIN TRANSACTION` at the beginning and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` at the end.

Then before the begin transaction add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;`. That will take care of batch failures.

After the inner proc with the error, check the error value for statement level errors e.g.

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
    RETURN 1; 
END
```

Comment: That was it thanks.  Wrapping it in a transaction bubbled it up correctly.  Thanks Russell.

Answer (score 0):

We do this with OUTPUT variables in T-SQL, though I only know the SQL side of it: you'll need to google getting an output parameter back from SQL with VBA.  Declare an output variable as a varchar, and set it immediately to '':

```
DECLARE @MyError VARCHAR(500) OUTPUT
SET @MyError = ''
```

Do your normal error checking in T-SQL and, if you do find an error, SET a description into the @MyError variable.  Your VBA code will always get the @MyError message, but it will normally be an empty string, ''.  If it isn't, then you go to your error handling in VBA.

Comment: Thanks @RussellFox That workaround should work - I'm just curious why this particular error doesn't bubble up to VBA directly, where others do.  Again, I can only think it's a severity thing.

Comment: It is a transaction issue with the statement failing but not the batch. See my answer.

Comment: [This](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic300275-131-1.aspx) post talks about that: it says severity 19 and higher should return, but the last post says you have to use the ADO error trapping rather than VBA's.

Comment: @RussellFox the point was that the error was terminating a stored procedure within a stored procedure.  The caller wasn't being terminated, hence neither ADO error trapping nor VBA error trapping worked.  That included bumping the error severity to 19.

Comment: Then you'll need error trapping around each call to a sub-proc and call RAISERROR in the main proc if a sub-proc fails.